# Как хранить модификации (изменения) сущностей?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, git, псевдокод

Есть задача оптимизировать работу реестра парковочных талонов. Есть куча параметров и текстовое наполнение. Задача: хранить "артефакт" изменений каждого пользователя (то есть видеть кто и какие параметры менял) И конечный вопрос такой: как отследить и хранить только измененные значения? нужно это потому, что копии текста занимают очень много места в бд. Да и какой смысл хранить к примеру 5000 символов, если была подправлена орфографическая ошибка, к примеру. В общем нужно что то типа гита, жду советов по реализации, хотя бы псевдокодом

Comment: А почему бы не использовать git в этом случае?

Comment: Потому что мне нужно хранить не изменения кода, а изменения бд sql =) Вы внимательно читали вопрос?)

Comment: Вы храните текст в БД, в то время как могли бы хранить его в git, у которого есть необходимые инструменты для отслеживания измений. Вы также можете в БД хранить не полностью весь текст, а git diff или patch, к примеру, хотя этим по сути вы будете эмулировать функционал git'а.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону использования [xdiff_string_diff()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.xdiff-string-diff.php) из расширения xdiff